# flowbite navbar toggler does not work but i just copied the code from their official website, i am using react js along with tailwind and flowbite

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

FlowBite
    
    
      Open main menu

Home

About

Services

Pricing

Contact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to attach flowbite's JS file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).